# Show that there are infinitely many primes congruent to 1 or 4 or to 2 or 3 modulo 5.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-writing, dirichlet-series

We are given the following Dirichlet character:
$\epsilon (n) =
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } n\equiv 1,4 \pmod 5,\\ 
-1 & \text{if } n\equiv 2,3 \pmod 5.
\end{cases}$

It is known that $\epsilon$ is multiplicative, i.e., $\epsilon(nm) = \epsilon(n)\epsilon(m)$ for any pair of relatively-prime integers $n$ and $m$.

I'm trying to define an appropriate $L$-series to show that there are infinitely many primes congruent to
1 or 4 modulo 5, and that there are infinitely many primes congruent to 2
or 3 modulo 5.

The $L$-series which I defined is
$1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4} + 1 + \cdots$,
but I'm stuck at proving with it.

Comment: Duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373750/show-that-there-are-infinitely-many-primes-which-are-pm-1-mod-5?rq=1

Comment: I'm not sure that it's the same question. Similar but different.

Answer (score 1):

My answer comes from Section 8.4 of *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers,* 5th ed., Wiley (New York), 1991 by I. Niven, H. S. Zuckerman, H. L. Montgomery.

First, we show that that there are infinitely many primes by using properties of the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).  We do that to provide a model and to use some of the findings for the answer to your question.

By combining the [formula for the logarithm of the zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series#Examples) with an [estimate for the zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Laurent_series), we find that
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\Lambda(n)}{\log n} \frac1{n^s} = \log \frac1{s - 1} + O(s - 1)$$
uniformly for $1 < s \le 2$ where $\Lambda(n)$ is the [von Mangoldt function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mangoldt_function), equal to $\log p$ if $n = p^k$ where $p$ is a prime and $k \ge 1$, or $0$ otherwise.  In that sum, the contribution made by the higher powers of the primes is
\begin{align}
\sum_p \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac1k \frac1{(p^k)^s} & \le \sum_p \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac1{p^{ks}}\\
& = \sum_p \frac1{p^{2s} (1 - 1/p)} &&\text{(sum of a geometric series)}\\
& \le \sum_p \frac1{p (p - 1)}\\
& = \text{some constant} \tag1
\end{align}
uniformly for $s \ge 1$.  Hence
$$\sum_p \frac1{p^s} = \log \frac1{s - 1} + O(1) \tag2$$
for $s > 1$.  If there were only finitely many primes, then the sum on the left would tend to a finite limit as $s$ tends to $1$ from above.  But that contradicts that the right side tends to infinity as $s$ tends to $1$ from above.  Hence, there are infinitely many primes.

We now answer your question.

Along with $\epsilon$, we need the principal Dirichlet character
$$\epsilon_0(n) =
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $n \equiv 1, 2, 3$ or $4 \pmod 5$, or}\\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

Consequently,
$$\frac{\epsilon_0(n) + \epsilon(n)}2 = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $n \equiv 1$ or $4 \pmod 5$, or}\\
0 & \text{otherwise, and}
\end{cases} \tag3$$
$$\frac{\epsilon_0(n) - \epsilon(n)}2 = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $n \equiv 2$ or $3 \pmod 5$, or}\\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases} \tag4$$
Let $\chi$ denote either $\epsilon_0$ or $\epsilon$.  Because $|\chi| \le 1$, the Dirchlet $L$-series
$$L(s,\chi) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\chi(n)}{n^s}$$
is absolutely convergent for $s > 1$.  Because $\chi$ is totally multiplicative, we can use a [special case of the Euler product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product#Definition) to write
$$L(s,\chi) = \prod_p \frac 1{1 - \chi(p)/p^s}$$
for $s > 1$.  Taking logarithms and arguing as in the proof of the [formula for the logarithm of the zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series#Examples), we deduce that
$$\log L(s, \chi) =  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\Lambda(n)}{\log n} \frac{\chi(n)}{n^s}$$
for $s > 1$.  From the estimate $(1)$, it follows that
$$\sum_p \frac{\chi(p)}{p^s} = \log L(s, \chi) + O(1) \tag5$$
for $s > 1$.  By the identities $(3)$ and $(4)$, we conclude that
$$\sum_{\substack{p \\ p \equiv 1 \text{ or } 4}} \frac1{p^s} = \frac{\log L(s, \epsilon_0) + \log L(s, \epsilon)}2 + O(1)$$
$$\sum_{\substack{p \\ p \equiv 2 \text{ or } 3}} \frac1{p^s} = \frac{\log L(s, \epsilon_0) - \log L(s, \epsilon)}2 + O(1)$$
for $s > 1$.

It remains to determine the behavior of $\log L(s, \epsilon_0)$ and of $\log L(s, \epsilon)$ as $s$ tends to $1$ from above.  If we take $\chi = \epsilon_0$ in $(5)$, we find that the sum on the left differs from that in $(2)$ only in that the prime $5$ is missing.  Hence from $(2)$ we deduce that
$$\log L(s, \epsilon_0) = \log \frac1{s - 1} + O(1)$$
for $s > 1$.

As for $L(s, \epsilon)$, we note first that the Dirichlet series $\sum \epsilon(n)/n^s$ is absolutely convergent only for $s > 1$.  We now show that this series is conditionally convergent for $0 < s \le 1$.  To that end, observe that the coefficient sum $\sum_{n \le x} \epsilon(n)$ takes only the values $0$ and $\pm 1$ and hence is uniformly bounded.  If $s$ is fixed, $s > 0$, then the sequence $1/n^s$ tends to $0$ monotonically.  Hence by [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test), the series $\sum \epsilon(n)/n^s$ converges.  Indeed, that series is uniformly convergent for $s \ge \delta > 0$.  Because each term is a continuous function of $s$, it follows that the sum $L(s, \epsilon) = \sum \epsilon(n)/n^s$ is a continuous function of $s$ for $s > 0$.  In particular, $L(s, \epsilon)$ tends to the finite limit $L(1, \epsilon)$ as $s$ tends to $1$.  Moreover, if we group the terms in $L(1, \epsilon)$ two a time, we can use the [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) to see that $1/2 - 1/12 < L(1, \epsilon) < 1/2$.  Hence, $L(1, \epsilon) > 0$, so that $\log L(s, \epsilon)$ tends to the finite limit $\log L(1, \epsilon)$ as $s$ tends to $1$ from above.  As $\log L(s, \epsilon) = O(1)$ uniformly for $s \ge 1$, on combining our estimates we find that
$$\sum_{\substack{p \\ p \equiv 1 \text{ or } 4}} \frac1{p^s} = \frac12 \log \frac1{s - 1} + O(1)$$
$$\sum_{\substack{p \\ p \equiv 2 \text{ or } 3}} \frac1{p^s} = \frac12 \log \frac1{s - 1} + O(1)$$
for $s > 1$.  Because the right sides tend to infinity as $s$ tends to $1$ from above, it follows that the sums on the left contain infinitely many terms.  Thus, there are infinitely many primes congruent to $1$ or $4$ and to $2$ or $3$ modulo $5$.